# Create grid using Bootstrap divs with variable height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a grid of divs (using Bootstrap3) (see image below).  I would like them act like a grid, but if they don't line up horizontally, they often are very much NOT lined up like a grid.

I thought this would be an easy solution, and I still think it might be, but for the life of me, I can't get it to work the way I'm hoping.

I've tried a lot of combinations of adding pull-left, and pull-right...etc, but again - nothing is working.

[image]

Quick example of what I mean - a grid of divs with dynamically varying heights:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum<br>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum<br>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum<br>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum<br>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up just using a `@media` query.  I added "col-right" class (is not a defined class - just made up) to the ones that should be on the right in large 2-column version, and on anything 1200px (lg) and over, have them float right.

This allowed the others (which default to `float:left;`) to wrap up next to them.

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: @screen-lg) {
    .col-right {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum<br>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-right">
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum<br>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum<br>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-right">
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum<br>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum<br>
</div>
```

Comment: elegant solution for a 2 column layout

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the way you're using columns (`.col-lg-6`). You should use only two columns, then divide your content between them.

Something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum<br>
            Lorem ipsum<br>
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum<br>
            Lorem ipsum<br>
            Lorem ipsum<br>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum<br>
            Lorem ipsum<br>
            Lorem ipsum<br>
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum<br>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6W5b/4/embedded/result/)**

Comment: This is a good answer, but I've expanded on my question to clarify a bit.  Sorry for missing the additional detail of how it should look when condensed.  Maybe I'm overthinking it - does something like what you're suggesting still work somehow?

Comment: The columns from my code will do what you're after and stack on top of each other on smaller screen sizes. You can check it out if you view my fiddle in a smaller window.

Comment: The columns work, but the div that should be second would be pushed way down below (in this case to 6th down), right?